# How to fix misnamed filesystem in GPT?

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, recovery, apfs

I restructured my drive in Windows messing up my partition table as the software I used did not recognize apfs.

In Mac recovery mode disk0s2 is recognised as a Linux Filesystem. It won't let me run fsck_apfs or mount it as apfs. How can I fix GPT so that it is recognised as an apfs again?. On a block level the filesystem is intact I have check CHS. GPT also looks hale (no corruption and does boot, simply doesn't recognise my apfs partition).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.